# unexpected output from bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I wrote a bash script to save images from a live stream. The streaming url is an updating jpeg file, so I wrote a variable to make a filename from the epoch.
The script does 2 things I hope someone can clear up for me. First, the images saved using the filename variable, are not readable as images.

Second, there are files being saved, but the names are not what I want.

the script source is:

```
#!/bin/bash

    while true; do
          date=`date +%s`
          ext=.jpg
          fname=$date$ext
          wget http://rawcam.ele.uri.edu/tmpfs/image.jpg -o $fname
          sleep 100
    done

and here is output:
$ ls
1489453852.jpg  1489453964.jpg  image.jpg    image.jpg.5  uri.sh
1489453951.jpg  1489453968.jpg  image.jpg.1  image.jpg.6
1489453954.jpg  1489453971.jpg  image.jpg.2  image.jpg.7
1489453958.jpg  1489453975.jpg  image.jpg.3  image.jpg.8
1489453961.jpg  1489453978.jpg  image.jpg.4  image.jpg.9
```

what am I doing wrong? I just want to save the file image.jpg, every few seconds, with filename as the epoch when it happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained by @steeldriver, the option needs to be an uppercase `O` for the output file. As a general rule when dealing with file names, and other strings, in a script, it's better to be safe and place them within quotes. That avoids some things the shell can do unexpectedly. The modified version of your script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
      date=`date +%s`
      ext=".jpg"
      fname="$date$ext"
      wget http://rawcam.ele.uri.edu/tmpfs/image.jpg -O "$fname"
      sleep 100
done
```

What was happening was that the epoch with `.jpg` was used to create the filename which was used as the log file for that run of the `wget` command. `wget` itself was downloading the `image.jpg` file, and to prevent "clobbering"* the previous download, added the incremented numbers, stating at `.1`, to each name.

*clobbering is when a new file overwrites an existing file with the same name.